# How do you detect already registered number with Account Kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is what I used to register the phone number with Account Kit

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{


   [super viewDidLoad];



  // initialize Account Kit
  if (_accountKit == nil) {
    // may also specify AKFResponseTypeAccessToken
    _accountKit = [[AKFAccountKit alloc] initWithResponseType:AKFResponseTypeAuthorizationCode];
  }

  // view controller for resuming login
  _pendingLoginViewController = [_accountKit viewControllerForLoginResume];
}
```

I have implemented Account kit using Swift. I have implemented to register the phone number, but I was wondering if I could detect if the phone is already registered within this the app.

Comment: Your code is clearly ObjC. Why tag it as Swift?

Comment: Fixed. Do you have any idea how to detect the registered user?

Comment: I don't mind either of them. OBJ-c/Swift

Answer (score 0):

You can check if somebody is already logged in like this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/ios#loginview

You can store the phone numbers and accountIDs in your own user tables to also verify if somebody has already created an account with that information. You can call the GraphAPI (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/graphapi) from your server to check if there have been any updates to those accounts.